# How to avoid Cusps and Corners when generating spline?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, spline, geometric-interpretation

I already asked this in [robotics.stackexchange.com](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24682/how-to-avoid-cusps-and-corners-when-generating-spline?noredirect=1#comment39801_24682), but no reply. So I've decided to ask here

[Here](https://github.com/GPrathap/motion_planning/blob/main/motion_planning_alg/scripts/cubic_spline_trajectory_generator.py#enroll-beta) I wrote Qubic spline trajectory generation. The following are the result.

**Spline that generated**
[image]

**Curvature of the spline**
[image]

**Yaw angle changes**
[image]

According to Figure 02, there is a sharp change in yaw angle, i.e., between 40 to 45 alone x-axis and the corresponding location of the trajectory is shown in blue in Figure 01.

**Question:**

**Is there a way to overcome such sudden changes when generating spline?**

Comment: Hmm. It looks like a representational issue caused by the wraparound in yaw angle (-180' to 180'). There is no actual cusp in the curve. If you don't wraparound angles, I think youll find it quite smooth.